# MongoDB search by tags with regular expression

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have model looks like:

`{_id: ..., tags: ["stackoverflow", "github", "bootstrap", ...]}`

How can I search for all items that match **BOTH** `/stack/` and `/git/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There mongo regex doc
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

```
db.collection.find(
{
$and :
    [
    { tags: { $regex: /git/ } },
    { tags: { $regex: /boot/ } }
    ]        
})
```

this solution may help you
[Searching in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463032/searching-in-mongodb/26463096#26463096)

Comment: It must capture items that match **both** /git/ and /stack/

Answer (score 0):

Just thought this question/previous answer can be improved:

The first solution that comes to mind when approaching this problem is :

```
db.collection.find({ tags: { $regex: /git/ }, tags: { $regex: /stack/ }}
```

But this will result in finding tag items which match only 'stack', because mongo builds this query in way which results in the first criteria overridden by second criteria(as they have the same key 'tag').

Hence the correct solution would be :

```
db.collection.find(
{
$and :
    [
    { tags: { $regex: /git/ } },
    { tags: { $regex: /stack/ } }
    ]        
})
```

Which will find documents which match both the regex conditions 'git' and 'stack' although the syntax is a bit contrived.