# MongoDB and Nested Arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with data like this:

```
{
    "Name": "Steven",
    "Children": [
        {
            "Name": "Liv",
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Name": "Milo"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Mia"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Chelsea"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Name": "Ozzy",
    "Children": [
        {
            "Name": "Jack",
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Name": "Pearl"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Kelly"
        }
    ]
}
```

Two questions

1. Can MongoDB flatten the arrays to a structure like this [Steven, Liv, Milo, Mia,Chelsea, Ozzy, Jack, Pearl,Kelly]
2. How can I find the a document where name is jack, no matter where in the structure it is placed

Comment: 1- the answer is `$unwind (aggregation)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463032/searching-in-mongodb/26463096#26463096

2- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463032/searching-in-mongodb/26463096#26463096

Comment: @Disposer: Thank you for your input. Isn't $unwind used to generate a document for each element in the array? You posted the same link twice.

Comment: @CruelIO you want two different output like first contains array of all name and seconds contains which match Children.Name="jack" or Children.Children.Name="jack" is right?

Comment: @yogesh That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, MongoDB does not perform recursive or arbitrary-depth operations on nested fields. To accomplish objectives 1 and 2 I would reconsider the structure of the data as an arbitrarily nested document is not a good way to model a tree in MongoDB. The MongoDB docs have a good section of [modelin tree structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) that present several options with examples. Pick the one that best suits your entire use case - they will all make 1 and 2 very easy.